# Would a vial of anticoagulated, warm blood attract mosquitoes?

Tags: hematology, parasitism

Would mosquitoes feed on free blood as an easy source of nutrients? They home in on veins by means of infrared light (heat detection). Also, blood needs to be in liquid form. So would they feed on anticoagulant-treated blood kept at 37<sup>o</sup>C? Or is there some physiological phenomenon that mosquitoes necessarily need to pierce something to draw in blood?

I am asking this, because just keeping a vial of blood at the end of a room might save us from mosquito bites.

Comment: Here's a link to the answer - https://redd.it/4h2j0g

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question if you found an answer elsewhere. Other option is to delete the post (not advised).

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia they locate "prey" by detecting CO2 and some other compounds, so I don't think mosquitoes will actually find the blood unless they're accidentally right on top of it.

And for your reason: if you have the equipment to regularly draw some blood, keep it at 37 C and have some anticoagulants on hand, you might be better off using some tried and true anti-mosquito tech (nets, insecticides, preventing them to breed in the local area).

Or maybe this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito_laser